# Regex not quite right

Tags: php, regex

I have a site crawler which displays a list of urls, but the problem is I cannot for the life of me get the last regex quite right. 
all urls end up listed as:

```
http://www.website.org/page1.html&--EFTTIUGJ4ITCyh0Frzb_LFXe_eHw
http://website.net/page2/&--EyqBLeFeCkSfmvA7p0cLrsy1Zm1g
http://foobar.website.com/page3.php&--E5WRBxuTOQikDIyBczaVXveOdRFg
```

The Urls can all be different and the only thing which seems static is the & symbol.
How would go abouts getting rid of the & symbol and everything beyond it to the right?

Here is what I have tried with the above results:

```
function getresults($sterm) {
$html = file_get_html($sterm);
$result = "";
// find all span tags with class=gb1
foreach($html->find('h3[class="r"]') as $ef)
{   
$result .=  $ef->outertext . '<br>';
}
return $result;
}

function geturl($url) {
  $var = $url;
  $result = "";

preg_match_all ("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\/url?q=\']+".
               "(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/",              

               $var, $matches);

$matches = $matches[1];

foreach($matches as $var)
{    
    $result .= $var."<br>";
}

echo preg_replace('/sa=U.*?usg=.*?AFQjCN/', "--" , $result);

}
```

Comment: Google for "URL [or URI] regular expression".

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for parsing HTML! use a DOM parser.

Comment: i am - there is still crap in the url to clean for some reason.

Comment: @Jack I am using Simple Html Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if url are ALWAYS in the same format, use explode :

```
<?php
$tmp = explode("&", "http://foobar.website.com/page3.php&--E5WRBxuTOQikDIyBczaVXveOdRFg");
?>
```

$tmp[0] should content "http://foobar.website.com/page3.php" and
$tmp[1] should content "--E5WRBxuTOQikDIyBczaVXveOdRFg"

Comment: http:// is about the only thing that is always the same everything else beyond that point up until the & sign could be any type of url. After the url its always random characters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to remove everything after the & character:

```
$result = substr($result, 0, strpos($result, '&'));
```

Comment: this seems to somehow work a bit but what happens it everything turns into one big long wrapped string with several urls as oppose to the line by line urls which were there before. Any recommendations?